# error when installing helm chart whith conditions

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I need to deploy three different certificates on different namespaces using helm chart. 
I create a template per certificate in the same file and add if conditions on each one in order to deloy only the needed certificate that i pass as a paramater in my helm install command,
My secret.yaml look like this :

```
{{- if eq .Values.val "paris_turf_support" }}
{{- range .Values.namespaces.paris_turf_support }}
{{- $ns := . -}}

apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
type: kubernetes.io/tls
metadata:
name: "tls-paris-turf.support"
namespace: {{ $ns }}
data:
    tls.crt: {{ $.Files.Get "tls-paris-turf.support.crt" | b64enc }}
    tls.key: {{ $.Files.Get "tls-paris-turf.support.key" | b64enc }}
{{- end }}

{{ else if eq .Values.val "geny_sports" }}
{{- range .Values.namespaces.geny_sports }}
{{- $ns := . -}}

apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
type: kubernetes.io/tls
metadata:
    name: "tls-geny-sports.com"
    namespace: {{ $ns }}
data:
    tls.crt: {{ $.Files.Get "tls-geny-sports.com.crt" | b64enc }}
    tls.key: {{ $.Files.Get "tls-geny-sports.com.key" | b64enc }}
{{- end }}

{{ else if eq .Values.val "paris_turf_com" }}
{{- range .Values.namespaces.paris_turf_com }}
{{- $ns := . -}}

apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
type: kubernetes.io/tls
metadata:
    name: "tls-paris-turf.com"
    namespace: {{ $ns }}
data:
    tls.crt: {{ $.Files.Get "tls-paris-turf.com.crt" | b64enc }}
    tls.key: {{ $.Files.Get "tls-paris-turf.com.key" | b64enc }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

when i run this command to install the helm chart :
`helm install secret-rel ./secret --values=./secret/values/dev.yaml --namespace=secret --set val="paris_turf_com"`

I get this error :
Error: YAML parse error on secret/templates/secret.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 9: mapping values are not allowed in this context

Need your help please

Comment: I am working on your use case right now but in the meantime you could check one thing please. `mapping values are not allowed in this context` means that the `yaml` is not valid.  Line 9 and 10 in your example is missing the indentations. Please correct them. If that is not enough, we will dig deeper.

Comment: thanks @OhHiMark i fix the indentations but i still have the same problem

Comment: Exact same error message? I would also get rid of the `""` (quotes) there.

Comment: yes it's the exact same error, i tried also to remove the "" and still have the same message

Answer (score 0):

`mapping values are not allowed in this context` means that there is an error in `.yaml` which makes it invalid.

There are plenty of online tools that can be used to validate yaml's syntax such as [YAML Lint](http://www.yamllint.com/).

In your particular use case the error says that there is an issue with line 9. Looking at your config we can see that you rae missing indentations in lines 9 and 10. It should look like this instead:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
type: kubernetes.io/tls
metadata:
  name: tls-paris-turf.support
  namespace: {{ $ns }}
```

Also you don't need to use double quotes (`" "`) for naming your Secrets. And as you already noticed, you should use `---` a line before `{{- end }}`

I hope it helps.

Answer (score -4):

finally i fix the problem, this is my secret.yaml :

```
{{- if eq .Values.val "paris_turf_support" }}
{{- range .Values.namespaces.paris_turf_support }}
{{- $ns := . -}}

apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
type: kubernetes.io/tls
metadata:
  name: tls-paris-turf.support
  namespace: {{ $ns }}
data:
  tls.crt: {{ $.Files.Get "tls-paris-turf.support.crt" | b64enc }}
  tls.key: {{ $.Files.Get "tls-paris-turf.support.key" | b64enc }}
---
{{- end }}
{{ else if eq .Values.val "geny_sports" }}
{{- range .Values.namespaces.geny_sports }}
{{- $ns := . -}}

apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
type: kubernetes.io/tls
metadata:
  name: tls-geny-sports.com
  namespace: {{ $ns }}
data:
  tls.crt: {{ $.Files.Get "tls-geny-sports.com.crt" | b64enc }}
  tls.key: {{ $.Files.Get "tls-geny-sports.com.key" | b64enc }}
---
{{- end }}
{{ else if eq .Values.val "paris_turf_com" }}
{{- range .Values.namespaces.paris_turf_com }}
{{- $ns := . -}}

apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
type: kubernetes.io/tls
metadata:
  name: tls-paris-turf.com
  namespace: {{ $ns }}
data:
  tls.crt: {{ $.Files.Get "tls-paris-turf.com.crt" | b64enc }}
  tls.key: {{ $.Files.Get "tls-paris-turf.com.key" | b64enc }}
---
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

Comment: So basically the tips I gave you plus adding the `---`?

Comment: @OhHiMark yes :)

Comment: In that case you should at least post a community wiki answer based on the info I have provided you. Or confirm via comments that it solved your problem so I could post an answer with explanation so the rest of the community would not only see the solution but also understand the reasoning behind it.